# How to use scanf after using while loop scanf !=EOF

Tags: c

I have to input a .in file into my program.gcc ./"file" < file.in
Because there are more than one input I have to use the While loop EOF, but
because of that I can't scanf again.
Here's a mock version of my program. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[100];
    int num;
    int count = 0;
    while( scanf("%d", &arr[count]) != EOF ) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Comment: What is 'more than one input' - more than one number (or more than one line of numbers) in an input file or more than one file to read?

Comment: oh sorry i didn't that clear, just more than one line of input. So a list of numbers.

Comment: And what results does your program produce? Scanf returns number of data fields read and assigned. In this case - the number of `int` values. So it will be either 1 on success or 0 on failure. Or it can be EOF if a reading error or end-of-file happens. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: @CiaPan OP certainly wants to read all the input from a re-directed `stdin` and then wants to to continue reading from the console (non-re-directed input).    It is not so much of what the program sample _produces_ as much as how it can _consume_ input from re-directed `stdin` and  then "not-re-directed" `stdin`.

Comment: the input file works and prints, but it doesn't allow for user input in terminal after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
freopen("con:", "r", stdin);//this for windows. "/dev/tty" for *nix ?
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Comment: Why force reading from console? The example shows OP wants to read from a file...

Comment: @CiaPan i don't think so. It has been completed by reading until EOF for file input.

Comment: See the end of the first line: `./"file" < file.in`

Comment: @CiaPan i know, so what?