# how to invoke EOF to standard input

Tags: c, terminal, eof

My program is using while scanf != EOF to input standard inputs from a .in file. as in ./"file" < file.in The problem is that I have to scanf from the terminal after that. Is there a way I can invoke EOF to the stdin so that the file stops scanning from file.in or maybe specify scanf to read from the terminal and not the file. I'm also only allowed to use scanf as this is a college assignment. This is a mock program of my issue. Thanks

```
int main() {
int arr[100];
int num;
int count = 0;
while( scanf("%d", &arr[count]) != EOF ) {
    count++;
}
printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

** Output is just the number of the first list of number, and scanf is completely ignored with no value in print num.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file `ctrl-d` in linux, `ctrl-z` in windows

Comment: Your `while` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: sorry so do i just printf of a command ctrl-d? Sorry i'm new to c

Comment: @Sarc , Press CTRL+D

Comment: but it has to be in the code, because the input data comes first and no prompt for user input comes up

Comment: Press it when running the code

Comment: sorry but I think my question got distorted. The while loop does end the file "file.in" but the second scanf still doesn't scan from prompt

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use scanf after using while loop scanf !=EOF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035002/how-to-use-scanf-after-using-while-loop-scanf-eof)

Answer (score 1):

To invoke/simulate `EOF` in `stdin` , press CTRL+Z if you are in windows. Else press CTRL+D when running the program.

Comment: sorry but I think my question got distorted. The while loop does end the file "file.in" but the second scanf still doesn't scan from prompt

Comment: Try closing the file before the `scanf` by using `fclose`

Comment: it still doesn't prompt for input

Comment: I Don't know about that...Try adding a space before `%d` of the last `scanf`. You could refer [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c) and [this](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html) for more info...

Answer (score 0):

scanf() return number of read chars.
you need feof() function, or compare returned value from scanf with 0

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: function feof(FILE *) return non zero if FILE * is EOF.
change your scanf() to feof(), in body of the loop add you scanf invocation.

Comment: May be need to replace scanf() to fscanf()

Comment: scanf and fscanf returning the number of read chars, these functions can not return EOF. If scanf read EOF, then scanf should return zero